# How to convert Emscripten FS error to string in Javascript

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

In [Emscripten FS functions](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api), `FS.ErrnoError` is thrown if there is an error.

The error number is provided, but the error message is always 'FS error' on the Javascript side of things. Is there a way I can get the string error message to display to the user, like `strerr` in C?

I looked through the APIs listed in the filesystem page but didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Does `-sEXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=strerror` work?